# Ghost NoReverseMatch Error for Django app in Parallels VM

Tags: python, django, templates, gunicorn, parallels

I have an odd behavior that I can't seem to track down a cause for.

I am using the Parallels Desktop Lite app running on High Sierra to create a new MacOS VM that is also running High Sierra for development.

I have successfully built a Postgres / Gunicorn / Nginx / Supervisor / Django stack. I am using Django==1.9.2 for legacy reasons.

I imported my legacy django website code and it runs fine. Now I start taking snapshots of the VM as I remove unneeded components from the Django site.

So say I have 10 apps in INSTALLED_APPS. I have successfully commented out / removed all of the code for 5 of them. I test the system, everything that is left runs fine. Then I take a snapshot of the VM and shut down for the day. The next day, I fire up the VM at the last snapshot to continue the process.

However, now when I pull up the django website, I get a NoReverseMatch error for a namespace of an app that I had previously removed. And it is at line 0 of the base_template no less (which doesn't have a line 0). If I search through all of the remaining code, there is no longer any reference to the offending namespace, so I don't understand where this is coming from.

Could it be django template caching? This error is reproducible as I go back through my snapshots, although the offending namespace name is different each time.

Thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 0):

**Update**
I still do not know why the ghost error happens when references to apps are commented out from templates, etc.

Turning off django caching did not have any effect.

What seemed to fix it was deleting the lines completely. After I deleted all of the lines I had previously commented out, the errors stopped happening.